# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expo.Permission.askAsync')

Tags: react-native, expo

i don't know what's the problem exactly but when i click on the button to choose image that erreur fire in the console 
here's my code

```
_checkPermissions = async () => {
    try {
      const { status } = await Permission.askAsync(Permission.CAMERA);
      this.setState({ camera: status });
      const { statusRoll } = await Permission.askAsync(Permission.CAMERA_ROLL);
      this.setState({ cameraRoll: statusRoll });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  findNewImage = async () => {
    try {
      this._checkPermissions();
      let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: "Images",
        allowsEditing: true,
        quality: 1
      });

      if (!result.cancelled) {
        this.setState({
          image: result.uri
        });
      } else {
        console.log("cancel");
      }
    } catch (err) {
     // console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Hi dude, did you find the solution?

Comment: Hello, did you find something ? I have the same problem

Comment: @JérômeW   here's  the solution that i've found  before [link](https://codeshare.io/ay6Xdw)

Answer (score 26):

to me what solved it was importing the permissions and imagePicker like this:

```
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
```

instead of this:

```
import Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
```

And that's basically because there is no default export

Comment: This is how I have mine imported using * and seeing these errors in Sentry.io

Answer (score 0):

It is `getAsync()`, not `askAsync()`

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions/

Comment: still same erreur undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expo.Permission.getAsync')  i'm using expo@^30.0.1

Comment: `Permisssions`, avec un ‘s’

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but I feel it's important to show a way that is currently working (as of 2022) and also `askAsync` is deprecated ...

## Getting image from (native) CAMERA

**TL;DR:** Even though we want "camera", we will actually **use [`expo-image-picker`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v42.0.0/sdk/imagepicker/#imagepickerlaunchcameraasyncoptions) FOR THE CAMERA (yes, you read right!)**

**I REPEAT: DO NOT USE <del>expo-camera</del> FOR CAMERA!**

### REMEMBER: USE `ImagePickerExpo.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()`
AND `ImagePickerExpo.launchCameraAsync()` 
NOT <del>Camera</del>....!

1. So install it first: `expo install expo-image-picker`
2. Then import everything, from it under 1 alias, I like to use `ImagePickerExpo` because `ImagePicker` itself is confusing since it can mean more libraries, + import all needed for this code - you can replace `Button` with any other button/pressable that supports **`onPress`** *(to use react-native-elements, you need to install it with `yarn add react-native-elements`)*
3. Create displaying component
4. Create a state & setter to save current image source
5. Create a function that requests the permissions and opens the **camera**
6. Return the coponent with button binding `onPress` on function from `5.` and `Image` that is displayed from the state from `4.` but only  when available.

## *working & tested(so far on android in expo go)* code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Image, Alert, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';

import * as ImagePickerExpo from 'expo-image-picker';


const MyCameraComponent = () => {
    const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);

    const openCameraWithPermission = async () => {
        let permissionResult = await ImagePickerExpo.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();

        if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
            Alert.alert("For this to work app needs camera roll permissions...");
            return;
        }

        let cameraResult = await ImagePickerExpo.launchCameraAsync({
            // ...
        });
        console.log(cameraResult);

        if (cameraResult.cancelled === true) {
            return;
        }

        setSelectedImage({ localUri: cameraResult.uri });
    };


    return (
        <View>

            <Button title='Take a photo' onPress={openCameraWithPermission}></Button>

            {(selectedImage !== null) && <Image
                source={{ uri: selectedImage.localUri }}
                style={styles.thumbnail}
            />}

        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    thumbnail: {
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        resizeMode: "contain"
    }
});

export default MyCameraComponent;
```

Note that I had to `style` the `Image` for it to display, it didn't display to me without proper styling which I find misleading, but I guess that's the react native way...

**BTW: This also works in Android emulator** (besides expo go in real Android device)

It also works on snack on desktop but only when you choose android (or Web) - https://snack.expo.dev/@jave.web/expo-camera-from-expo-image-picker

## Getting image from (native) gallery (not <del>camera</del>)

In case you're wondering how to do the same for gallery, the code is basically the same, you just need a different callback function for the button that uses `requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync` / `launchImageLibraryAsync` instead of the camera ones.

```
let openImagePickerAsync = async () => {
    let permissionResult = await ImagePickerExpo.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();

    if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
        Alert.alert("For this to work app needs media library/gallery permissions...");
        return;
    }

    let pickerResult = await ImagePickerExpo.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        presentationStyle: 0, // without this iOS was crashing
    });
    console.log(pickerResult);

    if (pickerResult.cancelled === true) {
        return;
    }

    setSelectedImage({ localUri: pickerResult.uri });
}
```